# how to install ora2pg on windows 7?

Tags: oracle, postgresql, ora2pg

i downloaded the zip file which was available online for free download but i a not able to install the downloaded file and run the file, can any one please help me installing the ora2pg on my windows machine please.

Comment: Neither is this a programming issue, nor do you provide much informations what you have tried. Did you try downloading it somewhere else? Running repair options on it? etc.pp

Comment: i have finished installing the strawberry perl and now i am trying to edit the config file where in i am not able to run the config file after editing.

Comment: DBI connect('host="Host_id";sid=""SID";port=1521','system',...) failed: E
RROR OCIEnvNlsCreate. Check ORACLE_HOME (Linux) env var  or PATH (Windows) and o
r NLS settings, permissions, etc. at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Ora2Pg.pm line
1491.
FATAL: -1 ... ERROR OCIEnvNlsCreate. Check ORACLE_HOME (Linux) env var  or PATH
(Windows) and or NLS settings, permissions, etc.
Aborting export... this error is occuring while trying to run batch file

Comment: i have set the oracle path, but now the error is different, its says  TNS:no listener (DBD ERROR: OCIServerAttach)

Answer (score 7):

Summary: I had to migrate few tables from Oracle database to PostgreSQL for my local development team to work on few modules of the application.

How? To save time, I did some research in postgreSQL blogs and found a tool ora2pg tool. This tool works best on UNIX as described in the blog. But there are quite good challenges when your PostgreSQL is on windows system.

Challenge:

- Install Perl 5.0 on windows
- Install Oracle DBD libraries to perl on windows
- Tables structure should exists prior running the tool
- Oracle client "Administrator" pack to be installed on windows.

Action:

Pre-requisites:

- Download and install perl on your windows from "http://strawberryperl.com/"
- Install [oracle client](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html) on your windows
- Download ora2pg software and untar to a known location on windows from "http://sourceforge.net/projects/ora2pg/files/13.0/ora2pg-13.0.tar.bz2/download"
- PostgreSQL is pre-installed on your windows machine. Else download it from "http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#windows"

Installation:

In cmd on your windows. Make sure you have internet connection:

```
cd <un tarred location>\ora2pg-15.2
perl Makefile.PL

dmake && dmake install

Set the environment variables:
Set ORACLE_HOME=<ORACLE_CLIENT_SOFTWARE_LOCATION>

Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<ORACLE_CLIENT_HOME>/lib
```

Install DBD::Oracle libraries - Internet is must

```
perl -MCPAN -e "install DBD::Oracle"
```

- Configuration file is created by default in `C:\ora2pg`
- Copy the template config file to original file name and edit
- Copy ora2pg_dist.conf to ora2pg.conf

Edit config file as in the example I used for one table:

```
ORACLE_HOME          C:\oracle\app\yaddanap\product\11.2.0\client_1
ORACLE_DSN  dbi:Oracle:host=172.31.232.253;sid=SUPLINUX
ORACLE_USER            system
ORACLE_PWD 1qaz2wsx!
USER_GRANTS     0
DEBUG                        0
EXPORT_SCHEMA       0
SCHEMA                      DB000001
CREATE_SCHEMA       0
COMPILE_SCHEMA     0
EXPORT_INVALID        0
TYPE                TABLE
ALLOW                        SL_01_DEPOS
DATA_LIMIT    150000
PG_DSN                       dbi:Pg:dbname=Drive1;host=localhost;port=5432
PG_USER                     kcc
PG_PWD                      kcc123
PRESERVE_CASE         0
BZIP2
GEN_USER_PWD         0
FKEY_DEFERRABLE     0
DEFER_FKEY    0
DROP_FKEY     0
DROP_INDEXES           0
PG_NUMERIC_TYPE    1
PG_INTEGER_TYPE     1
DEFAULT_NUMERIC bigint
KEEP_PKEY_NAMES 0
DISABLE_TRIGGERS 0
NOESCAPE       0
DISABLE_SEQUENCE   0
PLSQL_PGSQL 1
ORA_RESERVED_WORDS       audit,comment
FILE_PER_CONSTRAINT          0
FILE_PER_INDEX                     0
FILE_PER_TABLE         0
TRANSACTION committed
PG_SUPPORTS_WHEN                        1
PG_SUPPORTS_INSTEADOF    1
FILE_PER_FUNCTION  0
TRUNCATE_TABLE      0
FORCE_OWNER          0
STANDARD_CONFORMING_STRINGS 1
JOBS                1
ORACLE_COPIES         1
PARALLEL_TABLES      1
ALLOW_CODE_BREAK            1
XML_PRETTY   0
DISABLE_COMMENT         0
USE_RESERVED_WORDS        0
PKEY_IN_CREATE                    0
NULL_EQUAL_EMPTY 1
EXTERNAL_TO_FDW               1
ESTIMATE_COST                     0
COST_UNIT_VALUE                 5
DUMP_AS_HTML                    0
STOP_ON_ERROR                   1
TOP_MAX                                10
ALLOW_PARTITION                PARTNAME
USE_TABLESPACE                   0
PG_SUPPORTS_MVIEW          1
REORDERING_COLUMNS       0
SYNCHRONOUS_COMMIT      0
PG_SUPPORTS_CHECKOPTION           0
AUTODETECT_SPATIAL_TYPE 1
CONVERT_SRID                       1
DEFAULT_SRID                        4326
GEOMETRY_EXTRACT_TYPE  WKT
PREFIX_PARTITION     0
LOG_ON_ERROR                    0
PG_SUPPORTS_IFEXISTS         1
WITH_OID                   0
```

run the ora2pg now:

```
c:\ora2pg>ora2pg -c ora2pg.conf
```

Run the generated DDL statement in PostgreSQL to create structure of the table
Now edit ora2pg.conf file at one field as below again to copy the data now.

```
 TYPE                TABLE,INSERT
```

Re-run ora2pg tool now and you will see the data pooled.

```
c:\ora2pg>ora2pg -c ora2pg.conf

[========================>] 953/906 rows (105.2%) Table SL_01_DEPOS (952.9 recs/sec)

[========================>] 906/906 rows (100.0%) on total data (avg: 905.9 rec/sec
```

Comment: Une year later (or more) I'm trying to follow this tutorial. But can't execute ora2pg, its followed by the error: "No Perl script found in input". Any clues on why this is happening or how to fix it?

Comment: @chq You can try to run ora2pg from perl bin folder:
`cd C:\Strawberry\perl\site\bin`, then
`C:\Strawberry\perl\site\bin>ora2pg`

Answer (score -2):

I have shared step by step of LINUX installation, Please go through only respected command of windows, it will definitely work. 
Pre-installation steps:

1. ORACLE Client must be installed and ORACLE_HOME must be set.
2. Install perl (version 5.6 and above)

Installation steps:

1. Install DBI (database interface module)

   ```
   apt-get install cpanminus (for ubuntu)
   yum install cpanminus (for Linux)
   cpanm DBI
   ```
2. Install DBD::Oracle and DBD::Pg

   ```
   cpanm DBD::Oracle
   cpanm DBD::Pg
   ```
3. Download the latest version of ora2pg from http://sourceforge.net/projects/ora2pg/ and run the following commands:

   ```
   tar -xvf ora2pg-18.0.tar
   cd ora2pg-18.0/
   perl Makefile.PL
   su root
   make
   make install
   ```
4. Do the changes as per req
   By default Ora2Pg will look to ora2pg.conf configuration file into /etc/ora2pg/ directory.

   ```
   ORACLE_HOME /app/oracle/product/11.2.0
   ORACLE_DSN dbi:Oracle:host=[hostname];sid=[SID name]
   ORACLE_USER [SYSTEM]
   ORACLE_PWD [password]
   USER_GRANTS 1
   ```
5. Check the version of pra2pg:

   ```
   ora2pg SHOW_VERSION
   ```
6. Run the below command

   ```
   ora2pg -c /etc/ora2pg/ora2pg.conf
   ora2pg -c /etc/ora2pg/ora2pg.conf -p -P 10 -J 10 -L 1000000
   ```
7. .sql file will be created in the current directory have converted data into PostgreSql

Hope this will work.

Comment: The question was about installing ora2pg on **Windows 7** your explanation is for Linux.

Comment: Yes agree with you but you can easily find windows related similar command and on configuration file part will be remain in both environment.