# Install ora2pg [DBD::Oracle] manually on windows machine behind firewall no direct access to internet

Tags: postgresql, oracle, ora2pg

I am trying o install ora2pg and followed [ora2pg-on-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47345373/how-to-install-ora2pg-on-windows-7)

I am stuck at

> perl -MCPAN -e "install DBD::Oracle"

as my windows machine is behind a firewall and networking is not allowing this to open to it up to the internet. Is there a way to manually download and install **DBD::Oracle**. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Download the module](https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/M/MJ/MJEVANS/DBD-Oracle-1.80.tar.gz),
move it to the machine, unpack the archive and follow the instructions in the `INSTALL` file:

> As a last resort, you can manually install it. Download the tarball, untar it,
> install configure prerequisites (see below), then build it:
>
> ```
> % perl Makefile.PL
> % make && make test
> ```
>
> Then install it:
>
> ```
> % make install
> ```
>
> On Windows platforms, you should use `dmake` or `nmake`, instead of `make`.

Of course you'd need the `nmake` or `dmake` commands installed, a C compiler etc. It may be simpler to build it on a Windows machine with access to the internet and transfer the files to be installed to the target machine.

Comment: I tried to follow what you mentioned downloaded "DBD-Oracle-1.80.tar.gz" started cpan shell and tried to install the distribution using install DBD-Oracle-1.80.tar.gz but it still goes to the internet and get the below errors  ** C:\ora2pg>cpan
C:\Strawberry\perl\vendor\lib/Term/ReadLine/readline.pm line 410.
cpan> install DBD-Oracle-1.80.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
LWP failed with code[500] message[Can't connect to cpan.strawberryperl.com:80 (No such host is known. )]
Warning: no success downloading  *

Comment: Sorry; I read the instructions again.